# Data not updated on http response

Tags: angular

After http response comes I updated "user" field but it causes an error.

Error:Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined in [ name filed {{user.firstName}} in ProfileComponent@5:3]

If I write`<p> {{user | json}} </p>` I see the value of "user" field.

**Component**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    title:string = "Profile";
    public user:User;

    constructor(private _stateService:StateService,
                private _profileService:ProfileService) {
    }

    ngOnInit():any {
        this._profileService
            .getMe()
            .subscribe(
                user=> this.user = user
            )
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
<p>{{ user.firstName }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p> {{user?.firstName}} </p>
```

Look at here. This is my implementation (yours could be different).

http://plnkr.co/edit/NmxaIzOUmmnMriJeSnrA?p=preview - (Click on friends Tab)

try to remove Elvis operator (?) and see you'll get error. With (?) operator it is working fine.

Comment: You have just updated your question again. Okay btw doesn user have `.firstname` property?

Comment: how does `{{user|json}}` look like?

Comment: Yes sorry. User has firstName property. It's not related with any property. I tried different property it's also same.

Comment: { "userId": 2, "firstName": "Derya", "lastName": "Biçer", "fullName": "Derya Biçer", "email": "d@b.com" }

Comment: {{user?.firstName}} check with this. If it doesnt, you have to tell if your service runs out of angular2 zone.

Comment: Actually it's working if I set an array on response and I can Iterate over array on html. But I think "user" is undefined before request and html can not render user.firstName and throw exception. But don't know what to do?

Comment: Do you think should I define user like public user:User={} ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try <p [innerHtml]="user.firstname"></p>.
```

Also initialise the user in the constructor to a default value.

```
    constructor(private _stateService:StateService,
                private _profileService:ProfileService) {
        this.user = new User();// assuming user class has default constructor
    }
```

Comment: You are right my friend.

this.user=new User();   solved my problem. Thanks